# pseudocode to split number value to array of numbers

Tags: arrays, integers, pseudocode

How to write a pseudocode to split a number value to array of numbers? Let's say the number value is 12345. I need to convert it into [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Hi, welcome to cs.stackexchange. The answer you are searching is already on stackoverflow in a slightly different form. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780390/convert-a-number-to-a-list-of-integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num_to_arr(num):
   length_of_arr = log(num)+1 //log(num) base 10
   arr[length_of_arr]
   digit = 0

   while num > 0:
      digit = num % 10
      arr[length_of_arr - 1] = digit
      length_of_arr = length_of_arr - 1
      num = num / 10

return arr
```

This should do the job.

Comment: It must be strictly [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @camille Check the solution, I have added

Comment: thank you for the solution